# Integrate fullcalendar with extjs

Tags: jquery, extjs, integration, fullcalendar

I am trying to display the excellent fullcalendar in an extjs window that has loaded in response to a button click.

I can get the calendar to display in the window as follows:

//  .. grid config..

```
    //component bar
            tbar: [{
            text:'Calendar',
            tooltip: 'View leave calendar',
            disabled: false,
                iconCls:'icon-thisYr',//create icon
                handler: function(){           
                    var win;
                    // create the leave calendar window on the first click and reuse on          subsequent clicks
                    if(!win){
                        win = new Ext.Window({
                            layout:'fit',
                            width:750,
                            height:750,
                            closeAction:'hide',
                            plain: false,
                            //left: 150,
                            //top: 10,
                            items: [
                                // Set to div id in default.ctp to display jquery  fullcalendar when button is clicked.
                                calendar
                            ],
                            buttons: [{
                                text: 'Close',
                                handler: function(){
                                    win.hide();
                                }
                            }]
                        })
                        win.show();
                    }
                }
            }]
//etc rest of grid
```

and in my default.ctp view:

```
<!--Set placeholder for jquery fullcalendar called from events grid tbar button-->
<!--I think - set 'items' property on Ext.window to 'calendar' div-->
<div id="hello-win" class="x-hidden"> 
    <div class="x-window-header">Annual Leave Calendar</div> 
        <!--Placeholder for fullcalendar-->
        <div id="calendar">

            <script type='text/javascript'>
                $(document).ready(function() {
                    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({});
            </script> 

        </div> 
</div>
```

I am sure this is not the correct way to do this as the calendar only shows up sometimes and if I add some options to the fullcalendar initialisation then it won't display at all.

Any help on this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would take a different approach.  Instead of the following...

```
items: [
   // Set to div id in default.ctp ...
   calendar
],
```

.... I would create an empty DIV in the Ext JS window (using autoEl, for example) and then render the jQuery fullcalendar into the window's DIV.  I prefer this approach for several reasons: sometimes developers destroy windows after each use, it makes more sense to me to create window assets (div for the calendar) near the creation of the window, I create the calendar only if the user cares to view it, ...

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have created a div using autoel as you suggested and this works fine but I am not to sure how to activate fullcalendar now within this div..

Comment: I would wait until the Window is created - probably listen to the activate event.  Handle that event and create the calendar using code similar to above: $('#calendar').fullCalendar({});

Comment: I have implemented your suggestion - it works a treat however if I put  a sample event into the calendar initialisation although the event shows on the calendar I can't seem to get backgroundColor: 'red' to work (to set the color of an individual event). In chrome debug the element has the correct css applied (ie red) but it is crossed out - I presume this means it is being overridden somewhere else? Thanks for your help so far..

Comment: The Ext JS stylesheets are overriding the red.  If you can control the red style, try adding !important (bang important).  Otherwise, you can use the debugger to hunt down the Ext JS CSS causing the interference, and then edit it (ext-all.css) or add your own version of the style that renders the Ext JS impotent.  Make sense?

Comment: I have commented out the fullcalendar.print.css file and this enables the per event styling.

Comment: I have commented out the fullcalendar.print.css file and this enables the per event styling. So with that in mind I have now successfully integrated ext and fullcalendar. Thankyou for your help. I will post a detailed conclusion to help others.

Answer (score 2):

For the benefit of others here is how I implemented fullcalendar, extjs and cakephp.
Thanks to Upper Stage for earlier help.

1. Include all the fullcalendar files in your default.ctp before any extjs includes.
2. Don't include the fullcalendar print css file as it seems to interfere with custom colouring.
3. Create a feed function in your controller (events controller here) similar to below:

   function feed() {

   ```
       // jquery fullcalendar feed via feed.ctp
       Configure::write('debug', '0');     //turn debugging off; debugging breaks ajax
       $this->layout = "ajax";              //set the layout to Ajax so the ajax doesn't break
       $this->Event->recursive = 1;

       //1. Transform request parameters to MySQL datetime format.
       $mysqlstart = date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', $this->params['url']['start']);
       $mysqlend = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $this->params['url']['end']);

       //2. Get the events corresponding to the time range
       $conditions = array('Event.event_date BETWEEN ? AND ?' => array($mysqlstart,$mysqlend));
       $events = $this->Event->find('all',array('conditions' =>$conditions));

       //print_r($events);

       //3. Create the json array
       $rows = array();
       //var $backgroundColor
       for ($a=0; count($events)> $a; $a++) {

       //Is it an all day event - set to false?
       $all = ($events[$a]['Event']['allday'] == 0);
       // color each leave type
       if($events[$a]['Event']['leave_type'] == 'Annual Leave')
           {$backgroundColor = "green";}
       elseif($events[$a]['Event']['leave_type'] == 'Sick')
           {$backgroundColor = "red";}
       elseif ($events[$a]['Event']['leave_type'] == 'UA')
           {$backgroundColor = "orange";}
       // set nemonic for split shift
       if($events[$a]['Event']['split_shift'] == 1)
           {$splitShift = "+";}
       else
           {$splitShift = "";}

       //Create an event entry
       $rows[] = array('id' => $events[$a]['Event']['id'],
       'title' => $splitShift.$events[$a]['Employee']['name'],
       'start' => date('Y-m-d H:i', strtotime($events[$a]['Event']['event_date'])),
       'backgroundColor' => $backgroundColor
       );
       }
       $this->set('events',json_encode($rows));  //send events to the view

       }
   ```

This retrieves all the events between the start and end date params that fullcalendar sends with the url. It also maps and formats your database fields to fit the standard fullcalendar requirement.

1. Next add a view file called feed.ctp and put the events variable in it (within php tags of course):

   echo $events;
2. In your ext code (say to pop up a window with fullcalendar in it do the following:

   ```
                   win = new Ext.Window({
                   layout:'fit',
                   width:650,
                   height:650,
                   closeAction:'close',
                   plain: false,
                   title:'Annual Leave Calendar - Somerville House',
                   iconCls:'icon-thisYr',//create icon
                   modal: true,
       items: [
       { xtype: 'box',
       autoEl: { tag: 'div',
       html: '<div id="calendar"></div>'
       }
       }],
       listeners: {
           // when the window is activated
           'activate': function() {
           // call jquery fullcalendar
           $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
               header: {
               left: 'prevYear,prev,today,next,nextYear',
               center: 'title',
               right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
               },
               //height: 650,
               aspectRatio: 2,
                               eventTextColor: '#e5e5e5',
               // get calendar feed from events/feed controller function and return via feed.ctp
               events: 'http://'+host+'/shiftplanner/events/feed'
           });
           }
       }
               })
   ```

Using autoEl we can place the div that fullcalendar needs to be rendered in. We then listen to the activate event of the window and simply initialise fullcalendar in the normal way.
No problem!

Comment: Thank you for this guide. Although you wrote it almost 9 years ago, I successfully got CakePHP 4.0, ExtJS 4.2, and FullCalendar 4.2 to all play together, and render the calendar in a tabpanel. I had to figure out a few things that were different, but largely the process was very close to your steps. If anyone else is wondering if they can integrate those 3 frameworks, yes you can ;)